# How can I find out, if a page is full with reportlab PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am creating PDFs tables with Reportlib (with c.draw() ). I don´t know, when the page is full because of the dynamic content. How can I check out, if I am at the end of the page, so that I can add an footer and do c.showPage() ?

Answer (score 2):

canvas.draw() is too low level. If you want to stick with canvas.draw you have to take care of everything.

Instead, use Platypus and make Flowables, when you place them in your document `reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.BaseDocTemplate` has several hooks you can use to control placement and flux.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but my current implementation is:

```
[some page creation code, working its way down]
if ypos < 3 * cm: # near the bottom
    c.drawString(5 * cm, 2 * cm, "Cont...")
    c.showPage()
    ypos = 27 * cm
```

Hope that helps someone.